# AJAX execute php without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I don't understand javascript,AJAX very well and need to do this code fast, so if you guys can help, it would be great !
I have a like button on my webpage that allows users to like content:

The html code is as follows:

```
<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"><button name=\"like$i\">like</button></form>
```

And the php code:

```
for ($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i-=1) {
$primid = latest1($i);
$id = $user_data['id'];
if(isset($_POST["like" . $i]) && already_liked($id, $primid)===false) {
    add_like($id,$primid);

}
if(isset($_POST["like" . $i]) && already_liked($id, $primid)===true){
    echo "you have already liked this art";
}
}
```

All of the code works fine, but when I click the like button; the page refreshes wich is not ideal ...

I know you can use AJAX to fix this problem; i have looked for answers but they all seem to be for forms with content to insert ect ... 
I'm sorry if i seem lazy but i have to finish this fast and don't have time to learn ajax properly for the moment :S

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

Observe the following code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/some/file.php', //link to your php
    method: 'POST', // Method, you can use GET too
    data: $('#the-form').serialize() //get form values
}).done(function (response) { //works if response is success
    // Do something with the response
}).fail(function () { //works if response is fail
    // Whoops; show an error.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to compile the all things that you need:

JavaScript code:

```
function submitFormData(inputForm) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/some/file.php', //link to your php
        method: 'POST', // Method, you can use GET too
        data: $(inputForm).serialize() //get form values
    }).done(function (response) { //works if response is success
        // Do something with the response
    }).fail(function () { //works if response is fail
        // Whoops; show an error.
    });
}
```

Html code:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="button" onclick="submitFormData(this.form);" name="like$i">like</button>
</form>
```

Good luck with task implementation.

Comment: Just give the `type="button"` to button tag, else it will submit the form as by default it will consider as submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="likeForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="submit" name="like<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Like" />
</form>
```

**Sidenote:** `onsubmit="return false;"` is used to prevent `uncaught exception: out of memory` error in ajax.

**jQuery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#likeForm').submit(function(){
            var value = $(this).children().attr('name');
            var param = {value: value};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'yourpage.php',  // change this yourpage.php to point to a page where you want to process your ajax request
                cache: 'false',
                data: param,

                beforeSend: function(){
                    // before send
                },

                success: function(data){
                    // success
                },

                error: function(){
                    // error
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

**yourpage.php**

```
<?php

    for($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i-=1) {
        $primid = latest1($i);
        $id = $user_data['id'];
        if(isset($_POST['value']) && $_POST['value'] == "like" . $i && already_liked($id, $primid)===false) {
            add_like($id,$primid);

        }
        if(isset($_POST['value']) && $_POST['value'] == "like" . $i && already_liked($id, $primid)===true){
            echo "you have already liked this art";
        }
    }

?>
```